# looking at ".app" program files and editing them

Tags: macos

I want to look at how a program I have on my mac works. I imagine it has a lot of files? Am I mistaken here but I do not know how to open the ".app" program. I go to File and there is an open ⌘O option but that isn't what I am trying to do. I want to look at the inner working of the code and how the files all work together possibly edit, is this even a code related question? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

An .app isn't really a file; it's actually a folder which the Finder displays as a single file. If you click on the .app while holding down on the Control key and choose "Show Package Contents" from the resulting menu, you can see the individual files that constitute the application.